# Nginx ingress : combining rewrite-target and cookie sticky affinity annotations

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I want to build an app with sticky sessions, in order to keep each user to a dedicated pod in my kubernetes engine

Using a Nginx Ingress, it possible to use both annotations `rewrite-target` and `affinity: cookie` at the same time ?

Here is my Ingress `metadata:` section

```
metadata:
  name: front
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

    # sticky session
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "http-cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "18000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "18000
```

When calling my app I see in logs I'm calling pods randomly...

I've see there has been a resolved issue for this problem here : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1232

So it should work for me but it doesnt, do you know why ? Or do you know how to debug this issue ? thanks

Comment: what is the o/p of kubectl describe pods